# Unable to read data through a MAX485 module

Tags: serial, level-shifting, rs485, logic-level

I used arduino code in order to grab RS 485 data from a sensor.
The middleman is a MAX485 module.

[image]

However, I was unable to read the data, even with code that works from previous examples.
I hooked up an oscilloscope and this is what I got.
The blue is the RS485 signal from the sensor (A and B - A referenced to B), while the red signal is what I get at the RX pin of the arduino - after the MAX485 chip.

As you can see, the data appears corrupted for some reason.

[image]

Comment: Did you connect scope probe tip to A and probe ground lead to B?

Comment: `parse data` has a different meaning than `read data`

Comment: Did you connect power (Vcc and GND) to the RS485 module?

Comment: @Justme Yes, for the Blue channel. For the Red channel, I connected probe tip to RX pin on micro - after the MAX485 IC, and ground pin to ground.

Comment: @PeterBennett Yes, its connected with 5V Vcc and GND. The connections to the IC are fine, as I have worked with that chip again. Also, its properly set in RECEIVE mode, via its DE/RE pins.

Comment: In passing, that blue signal doesn't look too clean ... any idea why the level is so variable?

Comment: @jonathanjo The blue A wire channel looks garbage because B wire is shorted to ground.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have shorted the differential data line B to Ground with oscilloscope.

Don't do that. Data line B is not Ground and must not be grounded with scope probe.

Both A and B are data wires that have logic high and low levels.

The RS485 receiver sees B as 0V, and so even if A toggles between e.g. 5V and 0V, A-B voltage will always be non-negative and the RS485 receiver will not detect B being less than A so there will be no transitions on the logic level data output.

Comment: I connected the oscilloscope, after the code did not work. So this alone, does not produces the problem, as the problem already existed. For clarification (to make sure we are both on the same page), the Blue signal is produced by having one scope to the A of MAX485 input, while the GND of the same scope, is connected to B of the MAX485 input.

Comment: @user1584421 So if you fixed that then what do the waveforms look like?  Other possible reasons : You have A and B swapped, or missing a common reference between sensor and your board. Did you only connect A and B wires between devices or do they share a ground? Are there more devices on bus, so adding another one which has terminations make it not work? These are all made clear if you scope the A and B properly.